# Google Drive view access log

Tags: google-drive

I have a Google drive account. Multiple people access it from different devices. Is it possible to see which file was accessed from which device?

Searched online but found no useful resources.

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://admin.google.com/ac/reporting/audit/drive

Comment: I don't have a Gsuite account

Comment: I dont believe its logged on free accounts, only file change under "Activity"